# fgets and sscanf

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

This code is supposed to get integers from a file which is finput and sort it and gets the first integer in the file which is the number of integers to be sorted and the integers that follow are the integers to be sorted. I don't get how fgets and sscanf work together. Can someone explain how fgets and sscanf work in this code?

```
FILE *finput;
int *array_int, c1, no_elem;
char numlines[500];

fgets(numlines, 500, finput); 
array_int = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*no_elem);
if ((sscanf(numlines, "%d", &no_elem) == 1) &&  array_int!= NULL)
{
    for(c1=0; fgets(numlines, 500, finput) != NULL; )  
    {
        if (sscanf(numlines, "%d", &array_int[c1])==1) 
        {
            ++c1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`fgets` gets a string (i.e. a line of text) from the file.

`sscanf` parses a string based on the format string. It is reverse to `sprintf`. the `<x>printf` and matching `<x>scanf` functions allow formatted output and input accordingly, with a standard format string. For example, `"%d"` means "signed integer value", and in context of `<x>scanf` it means "read it into the next parameter in the following list of parameters" (your array member in your case).

You can parse directly from the file using `fscanf`, but using `fgets` + `sscanf` instead allows for more flexibility and might be safer.

Comment: Could you add an example of why `fscanf` might be unsafe?

Comment: @galymzhan can't think of any off the top of my head. Why?

Comment: So fgets gets the integer and sscanf assigns that integer to array_int? Am I right? Why is there a ==1 in sscanf?

Comment: @John, did you read the first sentence in my answer? How did you reach this conclusion? You're reading a text string, and then you parse the text string. These are two, distinct and unrelated actions. There's a function that does them both at once, or you can do them separately.

Comment: @littleadv Just curious, I've been using `fscanf` directly most of the time.

Comment: @littleadv I'm referring to my code. What I'm asking is, the fgets function in the code which is fgets(numlines, 500, finput) gets the string which contains the integers. And the sscanf function numlines, "%d", &array_int[c1] gets the string which is the number and extracts that value and the array_int will get that value as an integer. Is that right?

Comment: @John I think so... I'm not sure I followed you, but it seems you've followed me. fgets reads the string from the file. It doesn't care whats in it, as long as its less than 500 chars. sscanf reads an int from the string. It **does** care whats in it, will ignore everything until it can parse a number, and then ignore everything else. If it ended up ignoring the whole string - it will return 0 to mark you that it didn't find a number in there.

Comment: Oh I see, so sscanf will return 1 as long as it finds a string in numlines? Thank you very much! :D