# How can I implement a mechanism of some sort to prevent buffer overflows

Tags: c, file-io

I am currently working on a C based log parser (making a C version of the original bash based log parser) and I was wondering how i should go about preventing a buffer overflow in the event that there is botched input, Pretty much just a way to stop the program automatically when it runs out of memory, I have provided the code below as well, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
void main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  FILE *fd;
  char *name;
  name = getenv("MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME");
  char *filename;
  filename = malloc(sizeof "/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-.txt" - 1 +    strlen(name) + 1);
  if (!filename) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  sprintf(filename,"/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-%s.txt",name);
  char buff[1024];
  if ((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL)
  {
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while(!feof(fd))
    {
      memset(buff, 0x00, 1024);
      fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
    }
    printf("%s\n", buff);
  }
  else
  printf( "fail" );
}
```

this code below is an attempt at implementing fgets and scanf, but when i run the program it just sits there without displaying any output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
void main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  FILE *fd;
  char *name;
  name = getenv("MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME");
  char *filename;
  filename = malloc(sizeof "/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-.txt" - 1 +     strlen(name) + 1);
  if (!filename) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  sprintf(filename,"/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-%s.txt",name);
  char *buff;
  buff = malloc(1024);
  char *finbuff;
  finbuff = malloc(1024);
  if ((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL)
  {
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while(!feof(fd))
  {
      memset(buff, 0x00, 1024);
      memset(finbuff, 0x00, 1024);
     // fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
      fgets(buff, 1024, fd);
      scanf(buff, "%[^\n]\n", finbuff);
   }
    printf("%s\n", finbuff);
  }
  else
  printf( "fail" );
}
```

Comment: There is another buffer overflow in your program. If the environment variable `MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME` is long enough, the calculated buffer size for `filename` will wrap around and you allocate way too few bytes.

Comment: IIRC you need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` *before* you `#include` the headers, as they check for `_GNU_SOURCE` being defined or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `fscanf`, you should use a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` ... the advantage of `fgets()` is that you can specify the maximum number of bytes read, preventing buffer overflows.  Secondarily, replace `sprintf` with `snprintf`.

The basic way to prevent buffer overflows is to avoid functions that write to a buffer without specifying the maximum number of bytes to write.

Comment: ok great, and with this particular example, how would i implement what you have described with fgets and scanf? sort of new to C so do not have everything down down perfectly yet

Comment: @lacrosse1991 what I'm describing basically splits `fscanf` into two separate steps.  Use `fgets` to read a maximum of N bytes or up to some delimiter (such as an end-of-line character).  This prevents the buffer overflow.  Then use `scanf` (works the same as `fscanf`, only from a buffer, and not a file) to parse the buffer data read by `fgets`.

Comment: hello, thanks for the explanation was very helpful, although i think i may have messed up the implementation though, it compiles fine and all but when i run the program it just sits there, ive put this re-edited code below the original post above, if you could let me know what i did wrong i would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: @lacrosse1991 Oops, typo ... I meant `sscanf`, not `scanf` ... I missed the extra "s" character!

Comment: woohoo making progress :) now although it still shows up as blank, it just posts a blank line and exits instead of posting a blank line and then waiting for me to press enter, do you think i could possibly have fgets implemented improperly?

Comment: There's no reason for the program to wait on user input at the moment once it's completed the while-loop.  If you want to wait on the user, then you'll need to implement an extra call to `fgetc` or something of that nature after you've completed the while-loop and before your return from `main`.

Comment: oh yep, it was doing that before which was not desired, but my question was that at the moment, when executed the program just produces a blank line then immediately exits out, so was just wondering what could be causing that, do you think it could be how i have the variables setup in that the actual data is not being transferred from fgets to scanf?

Comment: @lacrosse1991 A quick way to confirm would be to print out the contents of `buff` rather than `finbuff` to make sure you're actually reading data from the file

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jason.

You can use fgets() to get a line of text into a character array, which will be null terminated (ie: a string). You can then use sscanf() to parse each line assuming that each line of text has a strict format.

The following post may also prove helpful.

[fgets and sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858809/fgets-and-sscanf)